# Is there an app that allows me to use Google Scholar on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, search, google

I'm looking for a native app that allows me to use [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) on my iPhone.

Does such an app exist?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct(native) application from Google for Google Scholar like Google Authenticator or Google Translator. But, there are some ios apps that supports Google Scholar search.

The best one, I can suggest you is [Papers](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/papers/id304655618?mt=8) which supports Google Scholar.

You can also go with apps like [Easy Search](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-search-for-google-facebook/id441132912?mt=8)($0.99) and [ArticleSearch](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/articlesearch/id401914624?mt=8)(Free).